# Proof of second homomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group, $H \leq G$ and $N \unlhd G$. Let $HN=\{hn │h \in H, n \in N\}$.

I finished

(a) $H \cap N \unlhd H$,

(b) $HN \leq G$,

(c) $N \subset HN$ and $N \unlhd HN$.

I have a question in

(d) $\frac {HN} N \simeq \frac H {H \cap N}$.

I think it will be proved by using the Fundamental Homomorhism Theorem (FHT):

Let $f: HN \to \frac H {H \cap N},  f(hn)=(H \cap N)h$.

Then $f(h_1 n_1 h_2 n_2) = f(h_1 h_2 n_1 n_2) = H \cap N(h_1 h_2)=(H \cap N h_1)(H \cap N h_2) = f(h_1 n_1) f(h_2 n_2)$ for $h_1, h_2 \in H, n_1, n_2 \in N$.

And $\ker f = N$.

Thus, by FHT, $\frac {HN} N \simeq \frac H {H \cap N}$.

My questions are:

(1) May I write $f(h_1 n_1 h_2 n_2) = f(h_1 h_2 n_1 n_2)$?

(2) If it is wrong, how can I fix $f$? Or what other methods can I use?

Comment: This is pretty hard to read. I recommend you use LaTeX to format your math.

Comment: thanks for editing problem!

Comment: There's a problem here. It need not be the case that $f(h_1n_1h_2n_2)=f(h_1h_2n_1n_2)$. The elements of $H$ need not commute with the elements of $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

It's much simpler the other way*
\begin{align*}
H&\rightarrow HN/N\\h&\mapsto hN
\end{align*}
It is indeed a homomorphism:
$$(hh')N=(hh')NN=h(h'N)N=h(Nh')N=(hN)(h'N).$$
It is surjective:
$$(hn)N=h(nN)=hN$$
The kernel is clealy made up of the $h\in H$ such that $\,hN=N   h\in N\iff h\in H\cap N$.

Hence the assertion by the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Bernard, why you conclude that about the kernel ? 
Let me explain myself: we want all the $h\in H$ for which: $\tau \left(h\right)=N$.
So $\tau \left(h\right)=hN=N$, so every $h\in N$ is setisfying (because the cossets of the an element of the cosset is himself).
So I dont understand two thing: 
1. Why the kernek made up of $h\in H$ $hN = Nh$ and not only what I wrote (maybe because hN = N but N = Nh eather?) and then why it is only and just only if h in the intersection ? 
About the last question, just a few words.

Comment: I mean if N was a normal sub-group of H, it was true eather, but how can we be sure that it is only and just only if condition?

Comment: Writing $hN=Nh$ was just a way to recall the hypothesis that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$., so $hN=Nh$. For the rest, it seems clear to me  that if $h\in H\cap N$, then $hN=N$ (because $h$ in invertible). Conversely, if $hN=N$, this means for any $n\in N$, there exists an $n'\in N$ such that $\;hn=n'$, whence $h=n'n^{-1}$, which lies in $N$. Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the delay. As I understand you also say the in that defined homomorphism the image is $HN\N$. Can you explain to me on thay example the first homomorphism theorem? 
I mean in other words must be: $HN\N = hN$, right ? And not $hN\in HN\N$. 
As I understand HN\N means hnN = hN. But I dont know to explain it in words, it is intuition, because I dont understand the first theorem until the end. Can you say a word about what I wrote, if you undertand my disundertsanding )?

Comment: Because we (me and some other stundents) asked ourself: "Wait a minute ... why this homomorphism's image is the qoutient group that we want from the first place?"